# Why do we need a pull-up resistor when there is a floating connection at the base of a transistor?

Tags: transistors, pic, pullup

[image]

Let's say that the base is connected to any normal PIC. My teacher was talking something like, "There will be a floating output at the base when nothing is connected so we use the R7 (10k) for safety." but i do not understand, 
1. Why will the output be floating?
2. Why do we need the 10K if the output is floating?

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) the output of the PIC will be floating (after reset) until the output is properly initialized by the software.

2) Strictly for a bipolar transistor you would not need such a resistor. When the base is floating the transistor will be OFF. However it is good practice to (pre) define floating inputs (the base of a transistor is an input) and usually a high-value resistor is used to switch the transistor OFF. A 10 k ohm resistor between Base and emitter will do that.

If you use a MOS transistor then you **MUST** always place such a resistor as the gate of a MOS transistor is isolated and can store a charge which will turn on the transistor untill you remove the charge. I always use a 1 Meg ohm to connect the gate such that the transistor will be OFF untill the microcontroller sets the gate voltage.

Comment: why is the output floating after we reset the PIC?

Comment: This is default state after reset. All GPIO go into high impedance input (effectively floating state). When MCU starts working, it takes some time to execute your program up to the point where you set that GPIO to output state.

Comment: Because that is the default state in which the microcontroller starts. the IO pins can be configured as floating, input or output but that initialization is done by the software stored on the microcontroller. Before the software can run, the micro first has to start up. To be safe all IOs are floating until initialized.

Comment: Ok i understood this one now  :)

Comment: Also, if the LED supply is higher than the micro controller supply (which it often is to allow the micro to switch more powerful loads) you could get a bias current flowing through the base, into the micro and through the input protection diode to the positive rail. It would turn on the transistor.

Comment: @FakeMoustache follow up :) ... So when there is a floating input(after reset) from the PIC to the base of the transistor, if we don't have the pull up resistor (R7) then what happens? Will the transistor fluctuate between ON/OFF state?